# Create a button that will update a database table in apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to create a button that will update a database table. I am using Oracle Application Express (APEX) 20.2. What I have done so far is create a regular button and then create a process that contains my PL SQL code that would update the table. The process is attached to the button by specifying in the "Server-side Condition" attribute to execute the process when the button is pressed. This has not work and would appreciate anyone who has any knowledge of doing this.

So all in all I am just looking to run PL SQL code that will update a table when the button is pressed.

This is the button
[APEX Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4CTh.jpg)

This is the process
[APEX Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrRf1.jpg)

The process is attached to the button
[APEX Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS1UF.jpg)

After pressing the button, this is what I see in Debug mode in runtime
[Debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9uv2.jpg)

After I press the button the current page stays in loading mode
[Loading mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rPX2.jpg)

Error I get after waiting for the loading tab to finish
[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUkHW.jpg)

I also tried using a dynamic action instead of a process but it did not work as well. Please see image of how I set the dynamic action.
[Dynamic action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw0VP.jpg)

Comment: That sounds correct.  Are you sure the PL/SQL code isn't getting executed?  Do you have debug calls in there that verify whether it is actually getting called?  Are you sure that you've chosen the right button?  Can you reproduce the problem on apex.oracle.com where we can look at your application to see what it's doing?

Comment: Have you looked at the debug output ? Enable debug in the developer toolbar, then click the button and look at the debug for that page. It is pretty readable and tells you exactly what is happening. This could give you an idea why it is not working as expected

Comment: @JustinCave I have added pictures to the post where you can see the Button, process and what I currently see in Debug mode.

Comment: @KoenLostrie I have added a picture on what my debug is desplaying after I pressed the button.

Comment: @SantiagoMartinez those debug entries are all from the page rendering process, (path info = show), you need the ones from the accept process - can you look for those, they should exist ? It is your code (we can't see it nor reproduce the issue) - debug it to figure out what is wrong. Is it a normal update  (as opposed to a restful service call, etc) ? Could it be hanging or waiting for a commit from another session ?  If you set condition to never, does the page submit work fine then ? are you able to execute the code in the page process in sql workshop without issues ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie I am new to Apex. How can I change to see debug entries from accept process? I did not see anything different that can be set besides path info = show? I dont know if its a normal update or a restful service call, how can I check that? Also I have run the code on TOAD and it works fine.

Comment: After you ran the code in Toad, did you commit?  My guess is that the Toad session is still open, it has uncommitted changes, your application is working just the way you want, and your application is timing out because it is trying to change one or more rows that Toad has locked.  If you commit in your Toad session, your APEX problems may disappear.

Comment: @JustinCave when I said I ran the code on TOAD it means that I just open an editor tab in TAOD and run the code in there. Not sure what you mean to commit in toad. I do currently have the TOAD session openned.

Comment: @SantiagoMartinez Type the word "commit" in the Toad session and run that new statement.  Or find the "commit" button in Toad.  I'm sure it has one, I'm not sure what it looks like.

Comment: @JustinCave you are correct! I had to commit in TOAD in order for the app to work.

Comment: Good to hear that ! In response to your last question for me: That debug report is just an interactive report, click on the "x" next to "page 8" to see all debug entries for an application. Note that you have to drill into them to see the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things.

Have you tried simply making a dynamic action that is triggered when the button is pressed.

Then you can have the action run PL/SQL code to do whatever you need.

If however what you are trying to do is update a table on the screen, then what you should try is making the button just submit the page. Then make a process with the editable region being the table you are working on, do the code in there. And in case you have other submits on the page that you dont want to trigger the code, just put in a button pressed condition in the process.

Comment: I tried using the dynamic action but it did not work. I am not trying to update a table on the screen as you mentioned. Please see the image I posted called "Dynamic action".

Answer (score 0):

The problem that was causing my button not to work was that I had a session in TOAD open and I did not commit my current query in TOAD's editor. I had to commit my changes in TOAD so that TOAD would not lock the rows that the code of the button in my APEX app was using/accessing. I also want to point out that my button worked without having to attach a process to it, instead the button needed a dynamic action attached to it as @TineO suggested.